# How to fetch all data from ssm parameter store in key value pairs using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I'm trying to fetch all data from ssm parameter store in key value pairs using Terraform

I found this:

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "parameter" {
  name = "/path/to/parameter"
}
```

which I can use to fetch one parameter each, but I want to fetch all of them in key value pairs.

Comment: When you say "all data from ssm parameter store", what data is "all data"?

Comment: all parameters saved in a single path @MarkoE

Comment: Then you probably want this data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameters_by_path.